# What would be the suggested rectifier for a simple lead/acid automotive battery charger?

Tags: rectifier, charger

In the past, I have made quite a few (simple) car battery chargers; basically with old TV set transformers and a full wave rectifier bridge they worked just fine.

Now I want experiment with a slightly more serious device.

I have already built an auto cut off circuit, very simple but got confused about which rectifier would be best.

This is for lead/acid car batteries, between 45Ah to 100Ah. Until now, I have used full wave rectifiers, but reading here and there some say a half wave rectifier will do better (some even say it charges faster, other say it helps to "shake" the battery internal electrolyte as to avoid sediment; don't know about that one though.) In some diagrams they use just one diode, in others they use two diodes in parallel as for raising the forward current. The transformers I would use are not central tapped.

Which rectifier is suggested? Why, other than economic reasons?

[image]

EDIT I updated the figure to reflect 12 VAC.  By experience: when the battery is connected to such weak transformers, the reading in the battery poles drops to 12 VDC, even charged it won't go further than 13.something VDC and the batteries doesn't get hot, won't explode, won't boil. Never had such problems. Again...my question is about rectifying the transformer's AC.

Comment: is this a school question?

Comment: No, I'm just an electronics enthusiastic. Know little electronics.

Comment: What is the purpose of this experiment, what is your end goal? These solutions are very crude and suitable only to illustrate very basic concepts or for emergency use.

Comment: The best way to charge a 12 volt lead acid battery is with a 14 volt to 15 volt DC supply current limited to the size of the battery. The rectified output of a 14 volt secondary is too high in voltage.

Comment: @Andyaka yes, understood, however my question is about which rectifier is more suitable...

Comment: @crasic well, where I live these are the standard...my experiment is to learn which rectifier would work best since I have seen these three flavors indistinctly.

Comment: All of these are very bad ideas to plug a lead-acid battery into. 14 V AC is *far* too high.

Comment: @Hearth VAC? ain't the rectifiers yielding DC?

Comment: @AramAlvarez a 14 volt AC supply has a peak voltage of about 20 volts. A single diode might drop about 1 volt (during the process of rectification) leaving you with a peak applied DC voltage across the 12 volt battery of about 19 volts. That is too high. It will likely exceed the 5 amp current rating of the transformer and some damage may occur. In other words, it doesn't make sense to analyse any of the scenarios in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka ok, I edited to state it is a 12 VAC transformer...which rectifier would be suggested.

Comment: I can only recommend that a design with a current limiting device is used (to protect your lead acid battery in case it's a small type with limited Ah capacity). The current limiter would then set what the maximum diode current will be and then you can pick a diode based on that current limit. Maybe you should google battery university (a real site) to see what they would recommend?

Comment: [Link to the Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-403-charging-lead-acid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've received enough comments about safely charging Lead-Acid batteries in a way that won't destroy or age them prematurely.  My answer only addresses the differences between the three circuits you included.

Figure 1 and 2 are both half-wave rectifiers.   No current flows in the negative half cycle.  The effective charge rate is half of the full-wave rectifier in Figure 3, where some current flows all the time (except for the crossover as diodes switch).

The two parallel diodes in Figure 2 are probably included to compensate for using some less-than-ideal diode that the designer had on hand.

Also: Your last paragraph (regarding experience with these circuits) suggests that the scrap transformers you typically use have a high impedance, which means that their output voltage reduces considerably as current increases.  This is common in consumer electronics power supplies as a way of limiting power. In your case, it does offer some safety as it acts to limit the initial charge rate, but not in any way you can really predict or control without doing some tests of the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Additional frame challenge.  Your excuse of "I can't afford quality chargers because ______" is *also* repeated by many people in first-world countries!   Well, the physics of batteries don't care what excuse you put in the _______.  Your battery life and performance WILL suffer from bad charging.  That is reality.  **You WILL be buying replacement batteries far more often, and that costs money too**.

*I note that many are in denial about this reality, and get angry when I call them out on it. But when a battery has failed, and they have to buy a new one, they go "sigh" and say "there's no choice to it". Their goal is to spend no money unless they're forced to, and they never make a mental connection to the economics of it.*

The only way your "I'm in a 3rd world country" argument works is if your country has an indigenous lead-acid battery industry using local-wage labor, making batteries very cheap locally... AND electronics must be imported using hard currency at foreign exchange rates.  But if that's the case, I wonder where you're getting all that copper. Copper is a world market.

Frame challenge:

I've designed and maintained too many homebrew battery chargers.  DON'T.

### Your skill is wasted "reinventing the wheel"

Think about the lowly bolt... say a 1/4"-20 hex head bolt 1" long.   Yes, you could *make one from scratch* out of 1/2" bar stock on a lathe and mill.  **But you wouldn't** - it would be time-consuming, costly, and the product would be *amateur-tier junk* compared to what you can buy cheap at the hardware store.

Modern battery chargers are like bolts.  They are extremely sophisticated with dedicated IC electronics to do correct 3-stage charging.  And because silicon is cheap, they are also highly *commodified*, which means you can buy them cheaper than you can make them.  Sort of like the bolt.

Switching power supplies only make this more extreme.  They replace that rather heavy iron and copper thing ($$$) with silicon electronics. Like I say, silicon is cheap, so the switching supply *actually ends up being cheaper* than the heavy transformer with copper at $4 a pound or whatever it is.

> I have already built an auto cut off circuit, very simple but got confused about which rectifier would be best.

Well, an "auto cutoff circuit" is still kindergarten-tier compared to the modern 3-stage charging built into any competent battery charger today.

I don't know what you're "saving" here because you're going to pay for it in degradation, shorter charge and shorter life of those batteries.

I'm serious. DIY battery chargers are the dumbest possible use of your intellect and skill.  Honestly, the time I wasted, I would have been better off using that time to say "Would you like fries with that?" and used the McDonald's wages to buy the chargers I was after.

It's like, suppose you love tinkering on cars. Great. But would you make a car tire?  Of course not, you'd buy it.

> This is for lead/acid car batteries, between 45Ah to 100Ah. Until now, I have used full wave rectifiers, but reading here and there some say a half wave rectifier will do better (some even say it charges faster, other say it helps to "shake" the battery internal electrolyte as to avoid sediment; don't know about that one though.) In some diagrams they use just one diode, in others they use two diodes in parallel as for raising the forward current. The transformers I would use are not central tapped.

Yeah, that's nonsense.  Again lead-acid charging has been the subject of countless billions of dollars of pro engineering, and if there was something to that, modern electronic battery chargers would *just do that*.

> Which rectifier is suggested? Why, other than economic reasons?

For economic reasons, diodes are cheap so go with bridge.

But for economic reasons, you just go silicon with the whole thing and not waste very costly copper on a transformer. What year is it? 1950?  You're better off cutting up your scrap transformers, selling the copper and iron, and buying a commercial battery charger that will Work Right and last decades - which means you get your time back.

---

*Man oh man, we had one mission-critical application where our hokey homebrew battery charger was just not reliable - it didn't even have an ammeter so we didn't know what it was doing.  We were chewing our nails off wondering if we'd have to turn away thousands of dollars in business every single day.  We're normally scroungers, but I said "ENOUGH!" and FedEx'ed out a very custom $400 battery charger for our weird voltage (for $250 shipping no less). OMG what a difference, best decision I ever made.  Ten years now and we haven't had to think about battery charging again. The only mistake we made was waiting **far** too long to pull the trigger on that purchase (hence the wasted $250).  I'll never make that mistake again.  I can't believe the time we wasted over the years clucking around with homebrew broken piece of carp chargers.*

*To waste time with commodity voltages like 6, 12, 24, 36, 48 volts - that's just dumb.  I had a weird voltage to contend with so I could count possible suppliers on the fingers of one hand. You have options!*

##### P.S. You notice I haven't said a thing about safety.

Comment: One single little detail: I live in a sub 3rd world country, so nope "...you can buy cheap at the hardware store". There is not such option here but reinvent the wheel!

Comment: "Think about the lowly bolt... say a 1/4"-20 hex head bolt 1" long. Yes, you could make one from scratch out of 1/2" bar stock on a lathe and mill. But you wouldn't - it would be time-consuming, costly, and the product would be amateur-tier junk compared to what you can buy cheap at the hardware store." <-- actually, that's what we do here!

Comment: @AramAlvarez I was suspecting this when I wrote my answer.  One need not even visit the third world to find people who for various reasons don't have easy access to cheap materials and must "make do".

Comment: @Theodore it would take a Quixote sized book to describe all the inventions and reinventions we must do :)

Comment: @AramAlvarez If you can't afford quality chargers, **how can you afford to replace batteries over and over?** See, that doesn't make any sense, unless you have a local indigenous battery industry that can make them very cheaply, *but no local electronics industry, forcing you to import chargers from the world market*. Possible I suppose.  But Occam's Razor says more likely, you're just not thinking clearly about the economics.  Hence me warning you of them.  Yeah, nobody likes that message lol.  It's not a fun message :(

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica we do have indigenous battery makers, almost homemade, they crack open discarded batteries, make the internal lead plates and seal them back with melted plastics also recycled. But still last about two years with normal usage...we are forced to invent things, we weld with homemade transformers, we rebuild 50s cars with soviet parts and "made" parts and adaptations.

Comment: I could explain in more details but I guess it will be totally off-topic and quite away electronics stuff :)